# Mask external api request in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an application using reactjs as frontend and python flask microservices as backend. From the reactjs application, i am calling a python external microservice api function using `await fetch(` but the external api url can be viewed in the network tab of the browser. Is there any way to mask or hide the python API URL? When we access the reactjs from the browser, for example, if we open `http://localhost:3000/users` in the browser then the actual request will be to the python microservice `http://localhost:5001/api/users`. Currently, the python api url can be viewed in the network tab, is it possible to avoid showing that python api url? or possible to mask it? so that it should only show the `http://localhost:3000/users` in the browser but the request should be to the `http://localhost:5001/api/users`? what about using a proxy?

Comment: @Phil, the python api url

Comment: Actually, the microservice is created using Python, it is a Python microservice. So, we have front end in reactjs and backend in python microservice and need to call the python api microservice from the reactjs and i need to mask that python api microservice api url

Answer (score 0):

> what about using a proxy?

In general, yes a proxy is the solution.

Most dev servers (eg [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy), Webpack, etc) have an option to proxy async requests so they look relative. For example

```js
// vite.config.js

export default {
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:5001',
    },
  },
};
```

and in your application code

```js
const res = await fetch('/api/users');
```

The browser will only see a request to `http://localhost:3000/api/users`

---

For production, you can configure a similar [reverse-proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) in your HTTP server. For example, with NGINX

```
root /path/to/your/react/app;
index index.html index.htm;

location /api {
  proxy_pass https://your-production-python-app-url;
}
```

The browser will only see a request to `https://your-react-app-url/api/users`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will check it.